# JQUERY refresh blinking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a little piece of code that should refresh part of a page. The refreshing part is working fine, only I notice on every refresh it blinks.. any suggestions how to get rid of the blinking?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("ajaxstatus.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('ajaxstatus.php');
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php file;

```
<?php
echo "1test<BR>";
echo "32333<BR>";
echo "2dddd2111<BR>";
echo "2dddcvbcvbd2111<BR>";
echo "2dsdfbddd2111<BR>";
?>
```

Comment: Well a hide / show I causing the blink.. You could go for the fadeIn / fadeOut?

Answer (score 0):

A small change to the code fixed it.. hope others can find use in it..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
    $.get('ajaxstatus.php', function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);    
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `fast` as a parameter in [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) and [show()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) functions like,

```
success: function() {
        $('#loading').hide('fast');
        $('#content').show('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `.show()` `.hide()` instead use `.html()` for content. as show hide cause browser twice to re-initiate, but html cause only once ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a div and a .get with jquery to get your data from another page on your website.

You can use setTimeOut(function, time)

```
$(function() {
    startRefresh(); });

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
    $.get('pagelink.php', function(data) {
        $('#content_div_id').html(data);    
    }); }
```